# Is it correct to use "even" with a subject and verb following

Tags: grammar

In English Grammar in Use 5th Edition, on page 224, it's written that "We do not use even + subject + verb" but at the top of the page there is an examplary sentence;

"These pictures are really awful. Even I take better pictures."

"I" is a subject and "take" is a verb so the structure is even+subject+verb but at the bottom of the page the book says it's incorrect to write even+subject+verb.

Comment: The book is wrong. In your example "even" modifies "I".

Comment: What @BillJ said. Even I can understand that.

Comment: The utterance *Even I take better pictures* requires an ***antecedent*** (for comparative "better" to refer back to). But *Even a king cannot cheat death* doesn't require any antecedent (simply that the audience be aware that "a king" is a very powerful person who can do many things that ordinary mortals can't do). That's to say, ***even** [statement]* always implies some kind of explicit or implicit contrast *(He takes pictures, **but** I take better ones; A king is very powerful, **but** he isn't immortal)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your book isn't exactly *wrong*, it is just suggesting a rule that doesn't exist instead of explaining when you can and cannot use 'even' this way.

It would be wrong to *begin* speaking with a statement like this:

> Even I take good pictures.

We would instead say something like:

> I take good pictures, surprisingly.

In your example, although "*even I take better pictures*" is a complete sentence, it is clearly a follow-up statement. It even uses a comparative adjective 'better', so it could not stand on its own. It is dependent on the previous sentence.

Comment: @astralbee Isn't ''the pictures'' the object in ''Even I take better pictures.'' ?

Comment: @orhantorun Yes! I thought from your question you were suggesting "I" was the subject, given that your book said "even + subject" was wrong?

Comment: The subject **is** "I". "Better pictures" is object of "take"

Comment: @BillJ In "I take better pictures" the subject would certainly be "I". But, as the OP's source tries to say, adding "even" to the beginning would not make a statement that stands alone. It is only acceptable as a continuation of the previous statement where the pictures are definitely the subject. These really need to be viewed as a whole.

Comment: The point is that your statement "Arguably, the subject is still 'the pictures" is wrong. In the sentence "Even I take better pictures" the subject can only be "I" irrespective of any situational considerations.  The OP's book says "We do not use even + subject + verb", which (if it was correct) would be a grammatical rule.